# Need to extract text messages out of an HTML document

Tags: html, vb.net, string, chat, data-extraction

**Hello, I have a long HTML document, this is only the part that interests me:**

`<iframe class="goog-te-menu-frame skiptranslate" src="javascript:void(0)" frameborder="0" style="display: none; visibility: visible;"></iframe><div class="chatbox3"><div class="chatbox2"><div class="chatbox"><div class="logwrapper" style="top: 89px; margin-right: 168px;"><div class="logbox"><div style="position: relative; min-height: 100%;"><div class="logitem"><p class="statuslog">You're now chatting with a random stranger. Say hi!</p></div><div class="logitem"><p class="strangermsg"><strong class="msgsource">Stranger:</strong> <span>hii there</span></p></div><div class="logitem"><p class="strangermsg"><strong class="msgsource">Stranger:</strong> <span>nice to meet you</span></p></div><div class="logitem"><p class="strangermsg"><strong class="msgsource">Stranger:</strong> <span>this is a text</span></p></div><div class="logitem"><p class="youmsg"><strong class="msgsource">You:</strong> <span>this text should not be taken</span></p></div><div class="logitem"><p class="statuslog">Stranger has disconnected.</p></div><div class="logitem"><div class="statuslog">`

**It outputs as follows:**

You're now chatting with a random stranger. Say hi!

Stranger: hii thereStranger: nice to meet youStranger: this is a textYou: this text should not be takenStranger has disconnected.

**I want to extract all messages sent by Stranger into strings (Visual Basic), and ignore messages sent by me and system messages such as `You are now chatting with a random stranger. Sai hi!` and `Stranger has disconnected.`
I have no idea on how I should approach this and need help, thank you.**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems like homework/no attempt made to try anything

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If anyone else is interested in such an operation, I've managed to simplify the process by applying the HTML code to another webbrowser then using the  `Document.Body.InnerHtml` property to get the text output in a richtextbox, so I can easily deal with the text instead of dealing with the HTML code.

```
OmegleHTML.Text = Omegle.Document.Body.InnerHtml
WebBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerHtml = OmegleHTML.Text
Log.Text = WebBrowser1.Document.Body.OuterText
```

I've also used the following code to get rid of any irrelevant text before the chat log:

```
Dim SInd, Eind As Integer
SInd = 0
Eind = Log.Text.IndexOf("You're now chatting with a random stranger. Say hi!")
Log.Text = Log.Text.Remove(SInd, Eind)
```

This is the closest I've got. If you have a better answer, please post it.