# VB.NET New Line not working

Tags: vb.net, string, newline

The code in my `Else` is never executed, though I have new lines in my `Log` (richtextbox). I tried `vbNewLine`, `Environment.NewLine` and `vbCrLf`..

What am I doing wrong?

```
 While (Pos < Log.Text.Length)
   Ch = Log.Text(Pos)
   If Ch <> vbNewLine AndAlso Ch <> Environment.NewLine AndAlso Ch <> vbCrLf Then
        Temp += Ch
   Else
        Messages(i) = Temp
        MsgBox(Messages(i))
        Temp = ""
        i += 1
    End If
    Pos += 1
End While
```

Comment: What is the variable "Log"? Is it an instance of Logging.Log?

Comment: @DiegoGoesBauleo No, sorry I didn't mention it. Log is a richtextbox.

Comment: Sorry wrote that other comment before you mentioned that log is a RTB.  It looks to me that CH is a char and all your newline's are multi character strings.  They will probably never be equal.  You could try adding `vbCr` and `vbLf` to the conditional.

Comment: @tinstaafl Wait, a newline isn't a single character?

Comment: Not always, many times it's a carriage return and a line feed

Comment: Well I did, however still not getting the `MsgBox` in the `Else` code..

Comment: Here's another thought.  RTB lines are stored as an array of strings, appropriately enough called Lines.  Try looping through that and checking for empty string to signify a blank line, and automatically skip any newline strings.

Comment: Nice! I'll try that.

Comment: Tried this, still no `MsgBox` displayed:
`i = 0 While (i < Log.Lines.Length) Messages(i) = Log.Lines(i) MsgBox(Messages(i)) i += 1 End While`

Comment: Your if statement is comparing a single character (Ch) to strings, some of which (like `vbCrLf`) consist of two characters. you will never get a match between Ch and `vbCrLf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding one of these to you if:

```
Ch <> vbLf
```

Or

```
Ch <> ChrW(10)
```

I believe it'll work while reading a RichTextBox input.

### EDIT

```
Private Sub ButtonClick_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonClick.Click
    Dim Log As RichTextBox = New RichTextBox()
    Log.Text = "<iframe class=""goog-te-menu-frame skiptranslate"" src=""javascript:void(0)"" frameborder=""0"" style=""display: none; visibility: visible;""></iframe><div class=""chatbox3""><div class=""chatbox2""><div class=""chatbox""><div class=""logwrapper"" style=""top: 89px; margin-right: 168px;""><div class=""logbox""><div style=""position: relative; min-height: 100%;""><div class=""logitem""><p class=""statuslog"">You're now chatting with a random stranger. Say hi!</p></div><div class=""logitem""><p class=""strangermsg""><strong class=""msgsource"">Stranger:</strong> <span>hii there</span></p></div><div class=""logitem""><p class=""strangermsg""><strong class=""msgsource"">Stranger:</strong> <span>nice to meet you</span></p></div><div class=""logitem""><p class=""strangermsg""><strong class=""msgsource"">Stranger:</strong> <span>this is a text</span></p></div><div class=""logitem""><p class=""youmsg""><strong class=""msgsource"">You:</strong> <span>this text should not be taken</span></p></div><div class=""logitem""><p class=""statuslog"">Stranger has disconnected.</p></div><div class=""logitem""><div class=""statuslog"">" & ChrW(10)

    Dim Pos As Integer = 0
    Dim Ch As Char

    While (Pos < Log.Text.Length)
        Ch = Log.Text(Pos)
        If Ch <> vbNewLine AndAlso Ch <> Environment.NewLine AndAlso Ch <> vbCrLf AndAlso Ch <> vbLf Then
            'Do nothing
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Else")
        End If
        Pos += 1
    End While

End Sub
```

Comment: Says CharW isn't declared, do I need to import something for it?

Comment: This may be an obvious question but here it goes anyway: do you actually have a line break in your RichTextBox? You have to actually hit enter to have one, a line wrap is not a line break. If you're 100% sure you have, how/where are you getting its value?

Comment: I don't hit enter, no. I'm importing the whole log from a chat website. More information on how I'm importing it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28934060/need-to-extract-text-messages-out-of-an-html-document

Comment: I see... in the specific text input you posted there are no line breaks, maybe that's why your else statement never gets executed. Try putting the cursor somewhere in the middle of the RichTextBox and hitting Enter once before running the code you posted above.

Comment: I thought that's probably why right there, but it still won't execute after I did hit enter in the richtextbox.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72806/discussion-between-diego-goes-bauleo-and-remon-ramy).